# Why do my stored procedure keeps throwing error that transaction is unusable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, transactions

I have written this procedure and it keeps throwing an error. I have used Commit transaction in the IF block, also used raiserror but nothing works. I don't understand that why would it still throw error. It keeps on throwing the error:

**Transaction has been completed; it's unusable.**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomerAppointments] 
        @CustomerName   varchar(200)= null,
        @ContactNo  varchar(20)= null       ,
        @VehicleRegNo   varchar(20)= null   ,
        @fk_VehicleMakeID   smallint= null,
        @VehicleModel   varchar(10)=null    ,
        @EntryDateTime  datetime= null,
        @AppointmentDate date= null,

        @fk_TimeSlotID  smallint,       
        @fk_JackID  tinyint= 0,         
        @fk_BookingModeID tinyint= 1, --Entry by a customer using web portal    
        @EntryUserID int= 1,

        @ReturnStatus int output,
        @ReturnMessage varchar(max) output,

        @ReturnBookingID int Output

AS
BEGIN

    Begin Try
     Begin Transaction tran1


        Declare @RowsCount int 

        Set @RowsCount= (Select count(*) from Bookings where fk_TimeSlotID= @fk_TimeSlotID and Convert(varchar(11), AppointmentDate,106)= Convert(varchar(11), @AppointmentDate, 106))

        If(@RowsCount > 0)
        Begin
                Set @ReturnStatus= 0
                Set @ReturnBookingID= 0
                Set @ReturnMessage= 'Appointment is not available on the selected date and time.'




        End

        Else

        Begin
                Set @EntryDateTime= GETDATE()

                Insert into Customers
                (
                    CustomerName        ,
                    ContactNo           ,
                    VehicleRegNo        ,
                    fk_VehicleMakeID    ,
                    VehicleModel        ,
                    EntryDateTime

                )
                Values
                (
                    @CustomerName       ,
                    @ContactNo          ,
                    @VehicleRegNo       ,
                    @fk_VehicleMakeID   ,
                    @VehicleModel       ,
                    @EntryDateTime
                )

                Declare @LastCustomerID int
                Set @LastCustomerID= IDENT_CURRENT('Customers')

                Insert into Bookings
                (
                    fk_CustomerID           ,
                    fk_TimeSlotID           ,
                    AppointmentDate         ,
                    OrderPlacementDateTime  ,
                    fk_JackID               ,
                    fk_BookingModeID        ,
                    EntryUserID             ,
                    EntryDateTime

                )
                Values
                (
                    @LastCustomerID         ,
                    @fk_TimeSlotID          ,
                    Convert(varchar(11),@AppointmentDate,106)       ,
                    GETDATE()               ,
                    @fk_JackID              ,
                    @fk_BookingModeID       ,
                    @EntryUserID            ,
                    @EntryDateTime
                )

                Set @ReturnStatus= 1
                Set @ReturnBookingID= IDENT_CURRENT('Bookings')
                Set @ReturnMessage= 'Your appointment# '+ Convert(varchar,@ReturnBookingID) + ' has been booked.'

                Commit Transaction tran1

        End



    End Try
    Begin Catch

        Rollback transaction tran1

        Set @ReturnStatus= 0
        Set @ReturnMessage= (Select ERROR_MESSAGE())
        Set @ReturnBookingID= 0

    End Catch


END
```

I don't understand that why would it still need transaction to be completed hence I am terminating it in IF block.

Comment: The If(@RowsCount > 0) branch neither commits or rollsback the open transaction.

Comment: I have tried both and none works

Comment: i do not see a reason why u have to use begin and commit trans, as you already using try/catch blocks. If you use that , write separate commits for `if` clause and `else`

Comment: Also use SCOPE_IDENTITY() **not** IDENT_CURRENT()

Comment: There is some good information here http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html if you want to learn about error handling and transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `COMMIT`needs to be outside your `IF`, as that's where you declared it. Otherwise, if you don't get into the right branch, your `COMMIT` will never be reached. Take this simple example:

```
DECLARE @i int;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN SampleTran;

    IF @I = 1 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO YourTable
        VALUES (GETDATE());
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO OtherTable
        VALUES (@I);
        COMMIT TRAN SampleTran;
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN SampleTran;
END CATCH
```

If `@i` has a value of 1, then the `COMMIT` statement will never be reached. The correct syntax would be:

```
DECLARE @i int;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN SampleTran;

    IF @I = 1 BEGIN
        INSERT INTO YourTable
        VALUES (GETDATE());
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        INSERT INTO OtherTable
        VALUES (@I);
        --Commit has moved
    END
    COMMIT TRAN SampleTran; --To after the END (of the IF)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN SampleTran;
END CATCH
```

Comment: @Stacky Could you elaborate?